# Memoir: reduce the space in the top of the page

Tags: spacing, margins, memoir

I'm using the `memoir` package to create my master thesis.

When I write a page with text and it goes to the next page, it gives me a vertical space after my header and down to my text.

What could cause this?
And how can I fix it?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english, oneside, 12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%Setup for the 'memoir' package (replace 'article')

%Margin
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\linespread{1.15}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.8mm}}

%Text in footer
\usepackage{lastpage} %Finds last page number
\usepackage{xspace} %Inserts necesary space bestween the page number, the dash and the total pagenumber
\newcommand{\footerText}{\thepage\xspace /\pageref{LastPage}}

% Specific chapter style.
% See more at: ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf
\chapterstyle{hangnum}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle} 

\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\\ \leftmark}{} 
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\\ \leftmark}{} 

\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\footerText}{} 
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\footerText}{} 

\makeatletter
    \makepsmarks{mystyle}{% Title in the header
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }} 
\makeatother

\makefootrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{0.4pt}
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\footerText}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\footerText}{}
\makefootrule{plain}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-40pt} 
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{0pt} 
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{35pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{102pt}
% \setlength{\textheight}{322pt}
\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} %Space from top of paper to header

\setheadfoot{29pt}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\chapter{MVE}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This gives the following:
[image]

Comment: Read the part of the manual about laying out the page. This is the distance between the header and the top of the text. It is also explained in the manual via a drawing.

Comment: And you should not make it too small.

Comment: Will check up on that, @daleif. And I shall post an answer to it when found.

Comment: I think this one is headsep.

Comment: Tried ``\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}`` - no changes.

Possible parameters interfering: 
``\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}``
``\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}``
``\setheadfoot{29pt}{2\onelineskip}``
``\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}``
Of cause ended with  ``\checkandfixthelayout``

Comment: Post a full minimal example. Also, you text may end up being a bit wide (in harder to read with those 2.5cm margins)

Comment: You can use the lipsum or kantlipsum packages to provide sample  filler text

Comment: Now with a MWE, @daleif
Looks like ``\setheaderspaces{*}{1\onelineskip}{*}`` instead of ``\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}`` will do the trick.

Comment: Please add package `showframe`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Slightly more confusing than helpful. But I notice I have no framed box in my footer...

Comment: The text is alright, it is the header that you moved upwards by using `\setheaderspaces`.

Comment: Yes, setting ``\setheaderspaces{*}{1\onelineskip}{*}`` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Solution seems to be the extra space added with these two properties:

```
\setheadfoot{29pt}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
```

The `2\onelineskip` defines (at least in this case) how much space there is from the horizontal line to the text starts/stops. Setting this to '1' gives a better result:

```
\setheadfoot{29pt}{1\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{1\onelineskip}{*}
```

The difference can be seen here:
[image]